# Migrate .SQLJ to maven project in netbeans

Tags: java, oracle, maven, netbeans, sqlj

I am currently migrating a project which using sqlj to do all the query. It is using JDeveloper to to develop the project.

Currently I need to create a new maven project using netbeans and I need to reuse those sqlj in this migrationg. But netbeans does not regonize sqlj.

Is there any solution on how do I migrate the sqlj to maven project in netbeans? I have imported the plugin in the maven but it have some error which is something like could not get the version.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>sqlj</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>sqlj</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <sqljDirs>
              <sqljDir>src\main</sqljDir>
            </sqljDirs>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>sqlj-maven-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlj</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

I have download the SQLJ translator in Oracle
[Oracle Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen)

I have install the translator.jar into my maven repository according to Maven 3rd party jar installation guide [Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Anyone have this migration case before that may guide me or give me some advice on this migration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a maven project using sqlj-maven-plugin, and works for me. (I'm using jdk6, mvn 3.1.1 and version 1.3 of the plugin).

I was getting the "Couldn't retrieve SQLJ Translator version info" error, but was an incompatibility error between my translator.jar and the plugin (I've submitted the correction [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/sqlj-maven-plugin/pull/2))